# Using nlohmann to parse a JSON file in a c++ program

Tags: c++, json, parsing, nlohmann-json

I have a very basic function below that I am trying to use in hopes of parsing a simple JSON object from a file. I have looked at similar questions that get the same `[json.exception.parse_error.101` which all point to the fact that the file is not being opened, however from my understanding that does not seem to be the issue here. I am able to print out the buffer stream which matches my JSON file exactly, so I know it is finding the file and extracting its contents. I am new to using the `nlohmann` library and am truly at a loss for why the program keeps throwing this error. I would greatly appreciate any pointers as to why this might be happening.

**.cpp file**

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ifstream myfile("test.json");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
 
        std::cout << myfile.rdbuf() << std::endl;
        nlohmann::json data = nlohmann::json::parse(myfile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**.json file**

```
{
    "firstName" : "Jane",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "age" : 100
}
```

**print statement/ error message**

```
{
    "firstName" : "Jane",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "age" : 100
}
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::parse_error'
  what():  [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 1: syntax error while parsing value - unexpected end of input; expected '[', '{', or a literal
```

**other solutions**

I have also tried using an older method to store the JSON object in my `data` variable using this operator `myfile >> data`, but the same error is thrown.

Comment: Is it possible your file has a BOM? Examine it with a hex editor, a text editor like Notepad++ that can tell you, or just print the first 5 or so bytes in hex in your program.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am using VS Code and the encoding is UTF-8

Comment: @anon UTF-8 encoded files can have a BOM though. It's in fact quite usual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ VS code differentiates between utf-8 and utf-8 with BOM, so I am certain it does not have BOM

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your file is bad somehow.

Comment: Either get rid of the `myfile.rdbuf()` so the json parser can parse the entire file or  use @rici's solution of seeking to beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout << myfile.rdbuf()` reads the entire file, and sends it to `std::cout`. Once that's done, there's no more data left to read, so when you pass `myfile` to `json::parse`, that function immediately gets an end of file indication.

If you want to both print the file and parse it, you'll need to rewind the file (seek to 0) or reopen it after you print it.

I don't know if this has anything to do with your original problem. If you haven't yet done this, try calling `json::parse` *before* you print the file (which will mean that the EOF will be received by `std::cout << myfile.rdbuf()` instead of `json::parse`; it still won't both print and parse the file).

Comment: I appreciate the insight to how .rdbuf() works. I had originally tried parsing prior to printing, but that also did not work. I ended up storing my file contents in a string and passing that to parse() which did work.

Comment: @anon. I'm sorry to hear that. Which is really the only possible response to "it didn't work", since "it didn't work" is a lament, not a problem description. What exactly did you do? What exactly was the result? If you want people to help you with your problems, you need to get into the habit of precisely describing the problem. I probably should have tried harder to explain `.rdbuf()`, but it's a big topic. It's `std::basic_ostream::operator<<( std::basic_streambuf* sb )` which reads the entire file; the `.rdbuf()` member function just returns a pointer to the streambuf.